# Remove padding on listview

Tags: android, layout

Hi I have an annoying problem I want to place a button as part of an action bar at the bottom of my listview but there is some padding just above below the last item of the listview I can't get rid of.  Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawingCacheQuality="high">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messagingListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="new_game"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `android:drawingCacheQuality="high"` from `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunately neither remove the extra padding the listview has

Comment: Share the screenshot

Comment: @Mohamed, there is not any `match_content`, but only `wrap_content`or `match_parent` (`fill_parent` is an equivalent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler layout would look like this :

- A vertical `LinearLayout` to contain the `ListView` and the action bar
- The `LinearLayout` used for the action bar has its height to `wrap_content` so it only gets the height required by its children
- The `ListView` has its `height` to `0dp` and its `weight` to `1` in order to let it take all the available space left by the action bar

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <LinearLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:drawingCacheQuality="high">
>     <ListView
>         android:id="@+id/messagingListView"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:divider="@null"
>         android:layout_margin="0dp"
>         android:dividerHeight="10dp"
>         android:paddingTop="10dp"
>         android:paddingRight="10dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="0dp"
>         android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:padding="0dp"
>         android:background="#FFFFFF">
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/button"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="new_game"
>             android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

If space remains, you should definitly show us the layout used for list items

Note :
In Android Studio, try to single click on the `LinearLayout` to let it be highlighted in the `Preview`, then on the `ListView` to see if there is a gap (Use the zoom).
If you see a gap with the layout just above, it's an `Android Studio Preview` bug on your computer, it works on every devices.